# Rpi wheezy duplicate capture on usb & dummy cards

Tags: alsa

I am trying to create an application that will stream audio with Darkice as well as provide a LED VU meter indication of the audio stream.

I have created a virtual card with .  This card is recognized by alsamixer, aplay, and arecord but I can not transfer the line-in signal from the usb card (hw:0,0) to the dummy card (hw:2,0).

I have tried several .asoundrc scripts that I found both in your Q&A as well as Google using alsa dmix, dsnoop, and multi but nothing has worked so far.

I am presently using one python program (LED_VU.py) that autostarts in one terminal, and the second python program containing Darkice (streamer.diDual.py) in a second terminal.  The configuration portion of the LED program is:

```
### LED VU Meter on RPI ###

#!/usr/bin/env python

import alsaaudio as AA
import audioop
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Define physical header pin numbers for 10 LEDs

RPiPins=[11,12,13,15,16,18,22,7,3,5]

#set all pins as output

for pin in RPiPins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

#Set up audio

card = 'hw:0,0'
```

The configuation portion of darkiceDual.cfg is:

```
# Darkice Configuration File - Generated by Streamer

[general]
duration      = 0     # duration of encoding, in seconds. 0 means forever
bufferSecs    = 5     # size of internal slip buffer in seconds
reconnect     = yes   # reconnect to server if disconnected

[input]
device        = hw:2,0  # alsa usb soundcard device for audio input
sampleRate    = 44100   # sample rate in Hz
bitsPerSample = 16      # bits per sample
channel       = 2       # channels. 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
```

My .asoundrc file is:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "mdev"
    route_policy "duplicate"

}

pcm.mdev {
    type multi

    slaves.a.pcm "hw:0,0"
    slaves.a.channels 2
    slaves.b.pcm "dmixer"
    slaves.b.channels 2

    bindings.0.slave a
    bindings.0.channel 0
    bindings.1.slave a
    bindings.1.channel 1
    bindings.2.slave b
    bindings.2.channel 0
    bindings.3.slave b
    bindings.3.channel 1
}

pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:2,0"
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        rate 44100
        channels 2
        format S16_LE
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The streamer will have no audio if I use hw:2,0 and have the 'Can not connect' error if I use hw:0,0 (LED_VU.py is using this).  If I change the card setting of the LED program to hw:2,0 the LEDs will lockup with all of them lit.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you for the help. The two programs both use the usb line-in as expected.

I am not able to use alsamixer or amixer now. Pulseaudio is causing the problem now. If it is installed, the LED_VU.py program will not run. When it is uninstalled, the python programs will run but not alsamixer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you want to run the VU meter and DarkIce from the same audio data, i.e., you need to allow two programs to share one recording device.

This can be done with the `dsnoop` plugin. Which is enabled by default for USB devices.

Tell both programs to record from the device `default`. If that was redefined, try `dsnoop:0` instead.